# Unambiguous but nondeterministic context-free language?

Tags: context-free

Whenever deterministic context-free languages are discussed, the webpage/textbook would always give a side note saying that although deterministic context-free languages are never ambiguous, unambiguous context-free languages may still be nondeterministic.

However, they never give an example. Is there a short, simple example of a context-free language that is

- unambiguous
- but nondeterministic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\{ww^R\mid w\in\{a,b\}^∗\}$ should do the job. The rest is up to you regarding proofs, such as providing an unambiguous grammar.

From [Example of Non-Linear, UnAmbiguous and Non-Deterministic CFL?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225302/example-of-non-linear-unambiguous-and-non-deterministic-cfl)
Third answer by Google.

Another one found similarly at [Non-Deterministic CFLs](http://www.cs.nuim.ie/~jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node38.html):  $\{x^ny^n \;\mid\; n \geq 0\} \cup \{x^ny^{2n} \;\mid\; n \geq 0\}$

Comment: So the language $ww^R$ does not have deterministic grammar? That's very interesting (so `yacc` shouldn't be able to parse it?)

Comment: @user54609 AFAIK, Yacc will parse a lot of languages that are not deterministic, or grammars that are not LR(k). It makes choices, when it has to (with consequences you may guess). But I am not a big Yacc user, so you should rather check the Yacc literature,.

Comment: I rather meant "parse without complaining about shift/reduce conflicts".